# Improve Couchbase Query for large dataset

Tags: couchbase, sql++, secondary-indexes

I have below bucket in Couchbase
I am using inner join to fetch the document

We have global secondary index for parent and child document.

- Total records in bucket : 4,300,000
- Query Execution : 5-7 sec
- RAM Used is 32 GB (allocated 90 GB)
- Disk Used is 20 GB

Its like we have parent document and making the several copy of child document with parent document

Example:

```
{
"document_id" : "p-001",
"document_desc" : "parent doc 1",
"document_type" : "parent"
},
{
"document_id" : "c-001",
"parent_document_id" : "p-001",
"document_desc" : "child doc of parent 1",
"document_type" : "child",
"document_status" : "NEW",
"customer_id" : "c-001"
},
{
"document_id" : "c-002",
"parent_document_id" : "p-001",
"document_desc" : "child doc of parent 1",
"document_type" : "child",
"document_status" : "NEW",
"customer_id" : "c-001"
}
```

I am using inner join to fetch the document

```
SELECT * FROM 
test_document AS parent 
JOIN 
test_document AS child
ON child.parent_document_id = parent.document_id
WHERE child.customer_id = 'c-001'
AND child.document_status IN ('NEW', 'OLD', 'OLDER')
```

Can I improve this query to make the query execution within few milliseconds (before 1 second)?
Or any other thoughts to achieve query execution before 1 seconds?

Comment: Would you please include the indexes that you are currently using? And maybe post the query execution plan?

Comment: We have created exactly same index as mentioned in below answer
Find the index created
Index 01 :  document_Id
Index 02 : document_Id, customer_id, document_status

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE ix1 ON test_document (customer_id, document_status, parent_document_id);
CREATE ix2 ON test_document (document_id);
```

As you  have predicate on child , switch JOIN order

```
SELECT *
FROM test_document AS child
JOIN test_document AS parent ON child.parent_document_id = parent.document_id
WHERE child.customer_id = 'c-001' AND child.document_status IN ['NEW', 'OLD', 'OLDER'];
```

Comment: We have tried above approach, but still no improvement in execution time

Check out the number of document below ::

Count of parent document : 427362
Count of child document : 3157

Comment: Did you feel number of documents here (to join) might affect the performance ?

Comment: EE ,  FROM test_document AS child JOIN test_document AS parent USE HASH (PROBE)